# issue when implementing WebDriverWait

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using the following code to scrape some data from a site, in this case team names from 'Toto'. This used to work fine until I implemented `WebdriverWait()` to replace `Time.sleep()` as I felt like that would be better. But now I get the following message when I run the code (this is only the relevant part of the error):

> File
> "C:\Users\axelz\PycharmProjects\ArbitrageBetting\ABFootball\Package\Functions.py",
> line 26, in Matchmaker1
> ATeamListUncorrected.append(ATeam.get_attribute('textContent'))
>
> selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message:
> stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

```
PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get(URL)

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'accept-cookie-consent')))
driver.find_element_by_id('accept-cookie-consent').click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'content-loader__load-more-link')))
driver.find_element_by_class_name('content-loader__load-more-link').click()

# Teams vinden en list van maken
HTeams = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('event-card__body__name__home')
ATeams = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('event-card__body__name__away')

MatchList = Matchmaker1(HTeams, ATeams, 'Toto', League)
```

The relevant part of the Matchmaker function is as follows:

```
ATeamListUncorrected = []
for ATeam in ATeams:
    ATeamListUncorrected.append(ATeam.get_attribute('textContent'))
```

Why does it throw this error and how can I resolve it?

Comment: A stale element is an element which is no longer available in the current document. This could be for a number of reasons - you have moved to a different webpage, you have refreshed the webpage, or you are in a different iFrame. Selenium stores these elements as references to the html element rather than the actual html element, this means if you do any of the above the element will become stale as it cannot be referenced anymore.

Do you do anything else with selenium before the part in the matchmaker function?

Comment: there's no wait or sleep between the click and your find_elements call.  I'd guess the lists are still populating when you get the webelement array(s).  Stale element will be thrown once a method is used on one of the webelement references.  In this case it's when you call .get_attribute.  You can either add a sleep, or catch stale element exceptions and re-call the find_elements call if caught.  (functionize and re-call if caught... with sanity count)

Comment: @pcalkins thanks, simply adding sleep worked